# create a table using user meta custom data

Tags: database, users

I am trying to create a table that is populated by the users:
name, points, training completed.  All of this data is in the users admin section.  Is there a plug in or code I can look at to understand how to create this?

EXAMPLE:

[image]

Comment: to associate data to users, you don't need a new table. just use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/

Answer (score 0):

See how the data is stored in the database in the table "wp_usermeta"

Find the storage keys for "points", "training completed"

Then using the function

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

```php
$users = get_users( $args ); 

foreach ( $users as $user ): 

    echo $user->ID;

    echo $user->display_name ;

    echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'KEY_POINTS', $single = true);

    echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'KEY_TRAINING_COMPLETE', $single = true);
endforeach;
```

Comment: I can not find the user data in the wp_usermeta.  The data is in the user profile is there some other place it could be located in?

Comment: display all user fields by id 

$um = get_user_meta ($user->ID); 

var_dump ($um);